# d3 bar chart labels not getting updated on updating the chart with the new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, label

Below is the code getting called everytime when I click on a button or an option in the drop down menu in order to update my d3 bar chart graph with the new data.

The bars in the chart are properly updated according to the new data, but the labels of the bar chart are not getting replaced with the new ones, instead both old and new labels are displayed.

Please suggest something so that old labels are not shown on bars.

```
function updateGraph(data) {

          // scale the range of the data
          x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.Country; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Value; })]);

          var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

          bars.enter().append("rect").attr("class", "bar");

          bars.transition().duration(200).attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.Country); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.Value); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Value); });

          var texts = svg.selectAll(".text").data(data);

          texts.enter().append("text").attr("class","label").attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.Country) + x.rangeBand() / 2 ; }  ))
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Value) + 1; })
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.Value; });  


          texts.transition().duration(200).attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.Country) + x.rangeBand() / 2 ; }  ))
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Value) + 1; })
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.Value; });  

          bars.exit().remove();

          svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

          svg.append("g")
             .attr("class", "x axis")
             .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
             .call(xAxis);

          svg.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Value");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding class to the text

This will select all DOM with class *text*

```
var texts = svg.selectAll(".text").data(data);



texts
.enter()
.append("text")
.attr("class","label text") <-- add text class here
.attr("x", (function(d) { return x(d.Country) + x.rangeBand() / 2 ; }  ))
                .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Value) + 1; })
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.Value; });
```

Now to remove all text on update

```
bars.exit().remove();
texts.exit().remove(); <--- add this to remove exited text
```

Comment: text.enter () line and texts.transitions() line both will come right?

Comment: I'm missing  .attr("class","label")  in transitions() only right?

Comment: I'm still able to see the old labels

Comment: can you give an example of how to add class to the text? what i should be writing in css?

Comment: No you need to add it class when you append the text to the selection.

Comment: done, also can you suggest how do i add a legend such that it gives colors to the bars and colors varies according to y-values?

Comment: I have asked question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801356/add-legends-to-a-d3-bar-chart